# How to use Apache Camel aggregator

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a very simple use case in which I want to put together a collection of stings and trying to use aggregator EIP for this. However when trying to start up the route it complains it cannot find an Aggregator Strategy:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AggregationStrategy or AggregationStrategyRef must be set on Aggregate
```

below is how I can reproduce the issue:

```
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class AggregatorTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    private static final List<String> LIST = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"one", "two", "three"});
    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                        .split().body()
                        .setHeader("cheese", constant("camembert"))
                        .aggregate(constant("all"))
                        .to("mock:end");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAggregateStrings() throws Exception {
        sendBody("direct:start", LIST);
    }
}
```

Of course a very easy way to fix this would be to create an Aggregation Strategy implementation and configure my route to use it. However I would like to understand why the way is set up now does not work. According to the camel documentation on [here](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html) :

> By default Camel uses DefaultAggregationCollection and
>   UseLatestAggregationStrategy, so this simple example will just keep
>   the latest received exchange for the given correlation Expression

I also noticed DefaultAggregationCollection is no longer part of the camel core. So what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the old documentation. The correct documentation is at: http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2

eg the list of EIPs has links to the correct documentation: http://camel.apache.org/eip

You can find examples from those links, and as well in this little example: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-aggregate/README.md

And the Camel in Action books has an EIP chapter where the aggregator is covered in much more details as well: http://camel.apache.org/books

Comment: page is not found for the above mentioned url

Answer (score -1):

I made a small video to demonstrate this EIP pattern using SpringBoot and Camel.

Have a look here: https://youtu.be/IdGuGGVv51Q